# C for loop not working properly without printf

Tags: c

I would like to list all permutations of n numbers. Until now everything seems normal but I encountered a very strange behaviour. With this code:

```
int **liste_permutations(int n){
    int i, fact = factorielle(n);
    int **tab=malloc(sizeof(int*)*fact);
    for(i=0; i<fact; ++i)
    {
            tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
            tab[0][i] = n-i;
    }

    for(i=1;i<fact;++i)
    {
            tab[i] = next_permutation(tab[i-1], n);
    printf(" ");
    }
    return tab;}
```

The output of this main()

```
    int **tab;
    tab = liste_permutations(3);
    for(i=0; i<factorielle(3); ++i)
    {

            for(j=0; j<3; ++j)
            {
                    printf("%d", tab[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
```

is

```
          321
   231
   213
   312
   132
   123
```

but if I change it to

```
int **liste_permutations(int n){
    int i, fact = factorielle(n);
    int **tab=malloc(sizeof(int*)*fact);
    for(i=0; i<fact; ++i)
    {
            tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
            tab[0][i] = n-i;
    }

    for(i=1;i<fact;++i)
    {
            tab[i] = next_permutation(tab[i-1], n);
    }
    return tab;}
```

the output of the main is :

```
321
231
321
231
321
231
```

And if I try to do this with n=5 for exemple, the output is blank (probably because it try to output 125 " ")

here is the next_permutation code :

```
int *next_permutation(int *t, int n){
    //printf("n = %d\n", n);
    int i, max, count;
    for(i=0;(i<n) && (max !=i); ++i)
    {
            if(t[i] == n)
            {
                    max = i;

            }
            if(t[i] == (t[i-1]+1))
            {
                    ++count;
                    if(count == (n-1))
                    {
                            return NULL;
                    }
            }

    }
    //printf("max = %d\n", max);
    if(n==1)
    {
            //printf("n=1\n");
            return NULL;
    }
    int *next = malloc(n);
    if(max == n-1)
    {
            //printf("max == n-1\n");
            int *s;
            s = malloc(sizeof(int));
            for(i=0; i<(n-1);++i)
            {
                    s[i]=t[i];
            }
            for(i=0; i<n-1; ++i)
            {
                    //printf("%d", s[i]);
            }
            //printf("\n");
            s = next_permutation(s, n-1);
            if(s == NULL)
            {
                    //printf("NUUUUUUl");
            //        next = NULL;
                    return NULL;
            }
            //printf("reprise en n = %d\n", n);
            for(i=1;i<n;++i)
            {
                    next[i] = s[i-1];
            }
            //printf("\n");
            free(s);
            next[0]=n;
            return next;
    }
    else
    {
            //printf("max != n-1\n");

            for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
            {
                    next[i] = t[i];
            }
            int tmp = next[max];
            next[max] = next[max+1];
            next[max+1] = tmp;
            for(i=0;i<n;++i)
            {
                    //printf("%d", next[i]);
            }
            //printf("\n");
            return next;
    }}
```

EDIT : modified what the 2 first comment said, but I still have the sam issue.

EDIT2 : Thank you to every body who helped me ! espescially to mweerden who showed me the right path (it was because count was uninitialized) !

Comment: Your `next_permutation` code is leaking memory right and left, not to mention all the initial allocations in `liste_permutations`: they are also gone after re-assignment. Rather than allocating a new array each time, you should pass an existing array for the result, i.e. `next_permutation(tab[i], tab[i-1], n)`

Comment: You want to trace the code using a debugger to learn what is really going on.

Comment: As you are new here I figured giving you a little hint. If one of the answers solved your problem you should accept that answer as the correct answer. To accept an answer you can click the little check mark below the vote buttons. It both increases your reputation and the reputation of the person who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

```
tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
```

`tab[i]` wants an array of `int`s (not an array of `int*`s)

Change to

```
tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

Also

```
int *s;
for(i=0; i<(n-1);++i)
{
    s[i]=t[i];
}
```

You don't reserve space for `s` (used uninitialized)

Comment: Thank you, I changed it but is still has the same behaviour...
Anyway thank you, I just earned a better note because of you !

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `printf` statement has this effect is because you are using a variable `max` that hasn't been initialised:

```
int i, max, count;
for(i=0;(i<n) && (max !=i); ++i)
```

When you don't initialise it, its value will be whatever was left there by other code when that piece of memory was last used. If you don't have the `printf` statement, the value will be whatever the last call to `next_permutation` left there. If the `printf` is there, the value will be some value that is left by the call to `printf`. Except for the first call to `next_permutation`, there the value is a leftover from `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of things wrong here. You start well:

```
int **tab=malloc(sizeof(int*)*fact);
```

But this is wrong:

```
for(i=0; i<fact; ++i)
{
    tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);
}
```

It should be:

```
    tab[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*n); // int, not int *
```

Then, your `next_permutation` loop:

```
for(i=1;i<fact;++i)
{
    tab[i] = next_permutation(tab[i-1], n);
    printf(" ");
}
```

You've already assigned to `tab[i]` above - and here you do it again?

Also, in `next_permutation` itself, you have the following line:

```
    if(t[i] == (t[i-1]+1))
```

The problem is that `i` can be `0` - indexing `t[-1]` is NOT what you want to do!